# Databricks File Save

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using Databricks on Azure and am using a library called OpenPyXl.

I'm running the sameple cosde shown [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file): and the last line of the code is:

```
wb.save('document.xlsx', as_template=False)
```

The code seems to run so I'm guessing it's storing the file somewhere on the cluster. Does anyone know where so that I can then transfer it to BLOB?

Comment: It is probably saving it in DBFS, more info [here](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html#databricks-file-system-dbfs)

Answer (score 1):

To save a file to the FileStore, put it in the /FileStore directory in DBFS:

> dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/my-stuff/my-file.txt", "Contents of my
>   file")

**Note:** The FileStore is a special folder within Databricks File System - DBFS where you can save files and have them accessible to your web browser. You can use the File Store to:

[image]

For more detials, refer "[Databricks - The FileStore](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/advanced/filestore.html#filestore)".

Hope this helps.